# Font size decreases instead of increasing

Tags: fontsize

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

...all the packages I need

\begin{document}


\chapter*{Abstract}
bla bla bla

\pagebreak

\input{dedication}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
bla bla bla

\tableofcontents

    \chapter{bla bla}
    \input{chapters/Introduction}

    \chapter{bla bla1}
    \input{chapters/Chapter1}

    \chapter{bla bla 2}
    \input{chapters/Chapter2}

    \chapter{bla bla 3}
    \input{chapters/Chapter3}

    \chapter{Conclusions}
    \input{chapters/Conclusion}

    \appendix
    \chapter{Matlab Code}
    \input{chapters/Appendix}

    \input{chapters/reference}

\end{document}
```

Strangely when I change the font size to 12pt to (for example) 18pt the font size decrease instead of increasing...any help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX will give you a warning that the 18pt option is not used. `12pt` is not an arbitrary length setting a font size it is a *name* of a class option, like `oneside` the names `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` just happen to look like lengths. As the option is not known, latex acts as if there were no option, so the default `10pt` is used.

Comment: I don't get it...I am sorry!

Comment: @Davide  `[18pt]` is like `[unknownname]` and just makes a warning that you see in the log about "unused global option" so in that case you get the default 10pt setting. If you use the `12pt` option then you get a document style based on a 12pt body text. If you want large text within the document use `\Large` or some such command.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it...the document class report I was using does not support more than 12 points.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - should the last sentence read (and for example `11pt` option sets the default font size to 1*0*.95pt)?

Comment: @Davide as I tried to explain that is not really the right way to think about it. The documentclass options are not lengths they are arbitrary names. report has exactly three options of that form, 10pt, 11pt and 12pt but those names do not directly relate to any particular lengths (and for example 11pt option sets the default font size to 10.95pt)